# How to wait for all Promises to be finished

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I like to run a set of functions in parallel and when all are done, I like to run some final stuff. My JavaScript looks like this:

```js
const logger = console;

const functionOne = function () {
  logger.info("Starting functionOne");
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      logger.info("Finished functionOne after 20 sec.");
    }, 20000);
  });
};
    
const functionTwo = function () {
  logger.info("Starting functionTwo");
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      logger.info("Finished functionTwo after 10 sec.");
    }, 10000);
  });
};

const runningFunctions = async function () {
  logger.info('Start jobs');
  functionOne();
  functionTwo();
}

runningFunctions();
logger.info(`All done after 20 sec.`);
```

In principle my log output should be this one:

```
2021-11-24 16:54:31.111 [info] -> Start jobs
2021-11-24 16:54:31.112 [info] -> Starting functionOne
2021-11-24 16:54:31.113 [info] -> Starting functionTwo
2021-11-24 16:54:41.115 [info] -> Finished functionTwo after 10 sec.
2021-11-24 16:54:51.115 [info] -> Finished functionOne after 20 sec.
2021-11-24 16:54:51.116 [info] -> All done after 20 sec.
```

I tried different solution, e.g.

```
runningFunctions().then(
  () => { logger.info(`All done after 20 sec.`) }
).catch(
  err => { logger.error(err) }
);
```

or

```
Promise.all([functionOne(), functionTwo()]).then(() => {
    logger.info(`All done after 20 sec.`);
});
```

and many others, but none of them worked as expected. In most cases message `All done after 20 sec.` comes immediately after functionOne/functionTwo started or the final log is not printed at all.

How do I have to write the script?

Comment: `Promise.all` is the way to go, but you'd need to `resolve` in your promises

Comment: And also you should resolve your promise first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to fix both `functionOne()` and `functionTwo()` so that they `resolve()` the promise they create when their timer fires.  Without that, they just create a promise that never resolves which isn't very useful and does not notify the caller when they are done.

Then, to run them in parallel, use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) which will let you call both functions and then it will track both returned promises together and the promise returned from the call to `Promise.all()` will resolve when both functions have completed or reject if either one of the functions rejected their promise.

If your example here, none of your promises rejects, but if you want to know when all promises have finished even if some reject, then you would use [`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) instead of `Promise.all()`.  The main difference is that `Promise.all()` will short-circuit and reject it's promise as soon as any promise you pass it rejects, whereas `Promise.allSettled()` will wait until all promises are done, regardless of resolve/reject.  Though you aren't using it here, the resolved value from `Promise.allSettled()` is different also so that you can tell which promises rejected and which resolved.

Here's a runnable (in the snippet) example that uses `Promise.all()`.
You can swap in `Promise.allSettled()` if that's the behavior you'd rather see:

```js
    const logger = console;

    const functionOne = function () {
      logger.info("Starting functionOne");
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(function () {
          logger.info("Finished functionOne after 20 sec.");
          resolve();
        }, 20000);
      });
    };
        
    const functionTwo = function () {
      logger.info("Starting functionTwo");
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(function () {
          logger.info("Finished functionTwo after 10 sec.");
          resolve();
        }, 10000);
      });
    };
    const runningFunctions = function () {
      logger.info('Start jobs');
      return Promise.all([functionOne(), functionTwo()]);
    }
    
    runningFunctions().then(() => {
        logger.info(`All done after 20 sec.`);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Note that if you run the snippet, you can see the actual timing of each log statement to verify that things happen in the appropriate time.

---

To run the two functions in sequence, you can just `await` each function call.  Here's a runnable (in the snippet) example:

```js
const logger = console;

const functionOne = function () {
  logger.info("Starting functionOne");
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      logger.info("Finished functionOne after 20 sec.");
      resolve();
    }, 20000);
  });
};
    
const functionTwo = function () {
  logger.info("Starting functionTwo");
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      logger.info("Finished functionTwo after 10 sec.");
      resolve();
    }, 10000);
  });
};
const runningFunctions = async function () {
  logger.info('Start jobs');
  await functionOne();
  await functionTwo();
}

runningFunctions().then(() => {
    logger.info(`All done after 30 sec.`);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

New in ES2020 is [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled).

> The `Promise.allSettled()` method returns a promise that resolves after all of the given promises have either fulfilled *or* rejected, with an array of objects that each describes the outcome of each promise.

This is slightly different to `Promise.all` which rejects immediately if any of the promises are rejected.

```js
function getData(count) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (count !== 2) res(count);
      rej(count);
    }, 1000);
  });
}

async function main() {
  const promises = [getData(1), getData(2), getData(3)];
  const response = await Promise.allSettled(promises);
  console.log(response);
}

main();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need `Promise.all()`?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

> The Promise.all() method takes an iterable of promises as an input,
> and returns a single Promise that resolves to an array of the results
> of the input promises. This returned promise will resolve when all of
> the input's promises have resolved, or if the input iterable contains
> no promises. It rejects immediately upon any of the input promises
> rejecting or non-promises throwing an error, and will reject with this
> first rejection message / error.

```
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise2 = 42;
const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
// expected output: Array [3, 42, "foo"]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, I noticed that you won't resolve the Promise:

Instead of

```
 return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      logger.info("Finished functionOne after 20 sec.");
    }, 20000);
```

Try

```
 return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function () {
       logger.info("Finished functionOne after 20 sec.");
       resolve(true); // or any value
    }, 20000);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Promise.all` is the way to go, but you'd need to `resolve` your promises

```
const logger = console;

const functionOne = function () {
  logger.info("Starting functionOne");
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      logger.info("Finished functionOne after 20 sec.");
      resolve(); // need to resolve
    }, 20000);
  });
};
    
const functionTwo = function () {
  logger.info("Starting functionTwo");
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      logger.info("Finished functionTwo after 10 sec.");
      resolve();
    }, 10000);
  });
};

Promise.all([functionOne(), functionTwo()]).then(() => {
    logger.info(`All done after 20 sec.`);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Better to share a jsfiddle /working code for quicker debugging. Here is a working solution for your ref.

Hope below JS fiddle helps.
https://jsfiddle.net/xqjvtypb/

```
const functionOne = function () {
  logger.info("Starting functionOne");
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      logger.info("Finished functionOne after 20 sec.");
    }, 20000);
  });
};
    
const functionTwo = function () {
  logger.info("Starting functionTwo");
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      logger.info("Finished functionTwo after 10 sec.");
    }, 10000);
  });
};

const runningFunctions = async function () {
  logger.info('Start jobs');
  Promise.all([functionOne(), functionTwo()]).then(() => {
    logger.info(`All done after 20 sec.`);
});
  /* functionOne() */;
  /* functionTwo() */;
}

runningFunctions().then(()=>{
// No action required.

});
```

Comment: Please save the commentary for comments & edit the question to improve the code blocks/snippets, when they can be improved. Please use snippets in lieu of JSFiddle links when feasible.

Answer (score -1):

Your main function should look like that:

```
const runningFunctions = async function () {
  logger.info('Start jobs');
  await functionOne();
  await functionTwo();
  logger.info(`All done after 20 sec.`);
}
```

If you wan't wait until another function will resolve you need to use async/await

More [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: I want to start the functions in parallel.